# PHP html characters coming in as question marks

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I have the head in my html set to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

However, apostrophes and commas are still coming in as question marks...

It seems to only be occurring in safari, but fine in mozilla and chrome. Is this a client side issue, or is there a method I could use to bring this data in from mysql to prevent the errors?

Here is my $sql statement, which appears to be prepared correctly:

```
$sql="select m_id, collection, collection_copy, collection_img, title, 

standalone from cmsmedia where collection = (select collection from cmsmedia where media_type=1 order by m_id desc limit 0,1) limit 0,1";


$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);

                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $m_id, $collection, $collection_copy, $collection_img, $title, $standalone);
                    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Here is the view code:

```
echo '<p>'.$collection_copy.'</p>';
```

Comment: Is your database set up to use UTF-8? What does your data look like?

Comment: That solved my issue, thanks. mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');